# Mysql : Finding empty time blocks between two dates and times?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to find out user's availability from database table:

```
primary id | UserId | startdate        | enddate
1          | 42     | 2014-05-18 09:00 | 2014-05-18 10:00
2          | 42     | 2014-05-18 11:00 | 2014-05-18 12:00
3          | 42     | 2014-05-18 14:00 | 2014-05-18 16:00
4          | 42     | 2014-05-18 18:00 | 2014-05-18 19:00
```

Let's consider above inserted data is user's busy time, I want to find out free time gap blocks from table between start time and end time.

```
BETWEEN 2014-05-18 11:00 AND 2014-05-18 19:00;
```

Let me add here schema of table for avoiding confusion:

```
Create Table availability (
  pid int not null,
  userId int not null,
  StartDate datetime,
  EndDate datetime
);

Insert Into availability values
  (1, 42, '2013-10-18 09:00', '2013-10-18 10:00'),
  (2, 42, '2013-10-18 11:00', '2013-10-18 12:00'),
  (3, 42, '2013-10-18 14:00', '2013-11-18 16:00'),
  (4, 42, '2013-10-18 18:00', '2013-11-18 19:00');
```

**REQUIREMENT:**
I wanted to find out free gap records like:

```
'2013-10-27 10:00' to '2013-10-28 11:00' - User is available for 1 hours and    
'2013-10-27 12:00' to '2013-10-28 14:00' - User is available for 2 hours and 
available start time is '2013-10-27 10:00' and '2013-10-27 12:00' respectively.
```

Comment: That is not that easy. But you can check if a user is free at a specific time. Would that help?

Comment: @juergen, May be that will not help me because i want to calculate user's total availability from empty blocks in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
SELECT t1.userId,
t1.enddate, MIN(t2.startdate),
MIN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, t1.enddate, t2.startdate))
FROM user t1
JOIN user t2 ON t1.UserId=t2.UserId 
AND t2.startdate > t1.enddate AND t2.pid > t1.pid
WHERE
t1.endDate >= '2013-10-18 09:00'
AND t2.startDate <= '2013-11-18 19:00'
GROUP BY t1.UserId, t1.endDate
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50d693/1

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I wanted to find out all the free gaps from table record between given start date and end date. Let's take example from 2014-05-18 09:00 to 2014-05-18 18:00 where user is free like 2014-05-18 10:00 to 2014-05-18 11:00 user is free for 1 hour.

Comment: LEFT JOIN where is not null?? Isn't that the same as JOIN ?!?

Comment: @Strawberry right, I have no idea why I made it that way :P

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, the easiest way is to list the hours when someone is free.  The following gets a list of hours when someone is available:

```
select (StartTime + interval n.n hour) as FreeHour
from (select cast('2014-05-18 11:00' as datetime) as StartTime,
             cast('2014-05-18 19:00' as datetime) as EndTime
     ) var join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
     ) n
     on StartTime + interval n.n hour <= EndTime 
where not exists (select 1
                  from availability a
                  where StartTime + interval n.n hour < a.EndDate and
                        StartTime + interval n.n hour >= a.StartDate
                 );
```

EDIT:

The general solution to your problem requires denormalizing the data.  The basic query is:

```
  select thedate, sum(isstart) as isstart, @cum := @cum + sum(isstart) as cum
  from ((select StartDate as thedate, 1 as isstart
         from availability a
         where userid = 42
        ) union all
        (select EndDate as thedate, -1 as isstart
         from availability a
         where userid = 42
        ) union all
        (select cast('2014-05-18 11:00' as datetime), 0 as isstart
        ) union all
        (select cast('2014-05-18 19:00' as datetime), 0 as isstart
        )
       ) t
  group by thedate cross join
           (select @cum := 0) var
  order by thedate
```

You then just choose the values where `cum = 0`.  The challenge is getting the next date from this list.  In MySQL that is a real pain, because you cannot use a CTE or view or window function, so you have to repeat the query.  This is why I think the first approach is probably better for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The core query can be this. You can dress it up as you like, but I'd handle all that stuff in the presentation layer...

```
SELECT a.enddate 'Available From'
     , MIN(b.startdate) 'To'
  FROM user a 
  JOIN user b 
    ON b.userid = a.user 
   AND b.startdate > a.enddate 
 GROUP 
    BY a.enddate
HAVING a.enddate < MIN(b.startdate)
```

For times outside the 'booked' range, you have to extend this a little with a UNION, or again handle the logic at the application level