# How do i select the free time between start time and end time in sql?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to select all the free time other that the mentioned ones for which the room is free.

eg table:

```
room starttime  endtime  date
1   |  12pm    |  1pm   |  2018-02-18 00:00:00.000
1   |  2pm     |  3pm   |  2018-02-18 00:00:00.000
1   |  3pm     |  5pm   |  2018-02-18 00:00:00.000
```

expected output eg:
        freetime
        6-12,5-10
Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

This is for a assignment where the room is booked for a class for particular starttime(date) and endtime(date) and date.

I need to find out the times when the class will be free.
Above free timings was just an example.

Comment: Because of the tag `tsql` i assume you are using SQL Server (MSSQL)? You also tagged MySQL.

Comment: What is the data type of `starttime` and `endtime` columns? How do you know the start of the "working time", like 6?

Comment: not sure how or why you expected freetime `5-10`?

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate of: [Mysql : Finding empty time blocks between two dates and times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721138/mysql-finding-empty-time-blocks-between-two-dates-and-times)

Comment: If you're still struggling, first figure out which RDBMS you're using, then see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If a room was booked over midnight how would that be represented?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: This is for a assignment where the room is booked for a class for particular starttime(date) and endtime(date) and date.

I need to find out the times when the class will be free. Above free timings was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
set dateformat ymd

-- Sample data
declare @MyTable
    table (room varchar(1), starttime varchar(4), endtime varchar(4), [date] datetime)
insert into @MyTable values ('1', '12pm', '1pm', '2018-02-18 00:00:00.000')
insert into @MyTable values ('1', '2pm', '3pm', '2018-02-18 00:00:00.000')
insert into @MyTable values ('1', '3pm', '5pm', '2018-02-18 00:00:00.000')

select d.[date], r.room, t.freehour
from
    (select cast(dateadd(hour, number, 0) as time) as freehour
            from master..spt_values where type = 'P' and number between 6 and 22) t,
    (select distinct room from @MyTable) r,
    (select distinct [date] as [date] from @MyTable) d
where not exists (
        select 1
        from @MyTable m
        where m.[date] = d.[date]
            and m.room = r.room
            and t.freehour between cast(m.starttime as time)
                and dateadd(hour,-1,cast(m.endtime as time))
        )
```